# jQuery: Hide element if user scrolled to the end of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scrolltop

I want to show an element if the user scrolls to a certan position on the page.
But I also want to hide the element if the user reaches the end of the page.

For now I only have the code to show the element:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 800) {
            $('.sticky-bottom').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.sticky-bottom').fadeOut();
        }

    });

} ( jQuery ) );
```

But how can I hide it at the end of the page? There is nothing like `.scrollBottom`.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
        $('.sticky-bottom').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-bottom').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

I added a fiddle (show up the console of the fiddle) to verify the addition of the margin that you need (800). It can be vary it depends on your design, I just use a console because I don't know if you are working with an object that is sticky to bottom for e.g.

https://jsfiddle.net/97s6p51n/

Comment: Looks good if I change the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. But now it's visible from the beginning. But I want to show it after the scrolls for a few pixels

Comment: @Cray you can add some pixels to the formula of the condition, like (innerheight - your_anticipation)

Comment: I tried it but I always get an error.  Something like `(window.innerHeight - 800)` doesn't work. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Cray I think I mees it up, is an addition, not substraction, check the fiddle I just update the answer